# Image button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I want to achieve is one of the basic things, but I have very little experience with jquery. This has failed using javascript so far, so maybe I 'll get it working using jquery.

I have an image, with id for styling, which on click will change to another image and back to first on click again and so on...

I am also using relative path, which is something like: "../Img/picture" and website is run locally, no server.

Afterwards, if I get that image change, it will display hidden element, or tweak shadows, many kind of things.

Comment: You should probably post what you're working with now.

Comment: I'd rather start with a fresh code for button. We ended up with a solid error yesterday.

    <script>
    if (document.getElementById("cm").getAttribute("src") == "../Img/Click_u.svg")
    {
        document.getElementById("cm").src = "../Img/Click_ch.svg";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("cm").src = "../Img/Click_u.svg";
    }
    </script>

Comment: Something like this. https://jsfiddle.net/pbLv6qqy/

Comment: @Nick Yeah, something like that Nick. Should I edit something in jquery to get this working ?